# Visual Studio stopped working with our TFS Server after a windows update

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Visual Studio had been working correctly with our TFS server, but after a windows update it broke.

Team Project was there, but when I tried to connect it gave me this error,

> "Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server."

I opened the Team Project Collection and it failed to connect. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried few things initially, closing and reopening VS, deleting the Team Project Collection and try to reconnect ect...

**The solution that did work:**

- Open up Windows Credential Manager (Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage your credentials)
- Remove all entries for that TFS server
- restart Visual Studios
- it works again!